# Get the text of the last td of the selected row

Tags: jquery

I have this table

```
<table id="search" class="order-table table ">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Group Title</th>
      <th>Group Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="in_modal">
    <tr><td>4</td><td>armin van buuren</td><td>arminvanbuuren</td><tr>
    <tr><td>5</td><td>krep</td><td>eden</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to retrieve the text of the last td of the currently selected row with

```
var le_selected = $('#search tr td:last-child', $(this).parents('tr.selected')).text();
alert(le_selected);
```

but this gives me blank.

How can i get the text of the last td?.

Comment: I believe this other question here can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475142/jquery-get-elements-in-a-specified-columns-of-an-html-table

Comment: You're missing a closing `tr` on the first table row.

Comment: @Kristoffer Should that be problem?.I have always liked to know how jquery responds to badly formed html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('tr.selected td:last-child').text()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need:

```
var le_selected = $(this).closest('tr.selected').find('td:last-child').text();
```

Or:

```
var le_selected = $('td:last-child', $(this).closest('tr.selected')).text();
```

`.parents()` is meant to return all matching parents (**could be more than one**). What you need is a method that returns the closest ancestor(**one**) of `this`: `.closest()`.

Comment: According the documentation of jquery the method `.parent()` returns only one element, while `parents()` climing up the DOM tree until the very first element and returns those.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var le_selected = $('td:last-child', $(this).parents('tr.selected')).text();
```

Your search will start at the selected tr, then drill down into its td descendants, looking for any last childs (assuming `this` is some node in the table`).

What you have will look inside the selected row for a element with id`search` then its tr and td descendants.